# How can I filter for specific combinations in Google Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

I have a data set with multiple lines per `Person` and the `Fruit Selection` on a particular date. I would like to create a filter to show me people that selected specific combinations (i.e. apple and pear).  Ideally I would like to be able to incorporate a date filter as well but this is a secondary need.

I tried using the following as a new field, as a metric, and as a calculated control field but I get the same error message for all of them:

```
CASE
  WHEN SUM(Apple) > 0 AND SUM(Orange) > 0 AND SUM(Pear) = 0 THEN 'Apple and Orange'
  WHEN SUM(Apple) > 0 AND SUM(Orange) = 0 AND SUM(Pear) = 0 THEN 'Apple'
  WHEN SUM(Apple) = 0 AND SUM(Orange) = 0 AND SUM(Pear) > 0 THEN 'Pear'
  WHEN SUM(Apple) = 0 AND SUM(Orange) > 0 AND SUM(Pear) = 0 THEN 'Orange'
  WHEN SUM(Apple) > 0 AND SUM(Orange) = 0 AND SUM(Pear) > 0 THEN 'Apple and Pear'
  WHEN SUM(Apple) > 0 AND SUM(Orange) > 0 AND SUM(Pear) > 0 THEN 'Orange and Pear'
  ELSE 'other'
END
```

I keep receiving this error message:

> Metric expressions and aggregations are not allowed in this expression.

however I don't have any metrics included in the calculation.

##### Resources that might help:

Data layout ([Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nNYsvOeTCkIp7crxsXE8kvklPNlTQXmgh3XLfITppNc/edit?usp=sharing)):

| Person | date | Fruit Selection | Apple | Orange | Pear |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Person A | 1/1/2019 | Apple | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Person A | 2/1/2019 | Orange | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Person B | 2/2/2019 | Pear | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| Person B | 2/3/2020 | Pear | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| Person B | 2/4/2020 | Apple | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Person C | 2/5/2021 | Apple | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Person C | 2/6/2019 | Orange | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| Person C | 2/7/2020 | Pear | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| Person C | 2/8/2019 | Pear | 0 | 0 | 1 |

[Google Data Studio report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/26f9466c-3ae5-46c2-9246-3ae943024873)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom values can be used in a the [control](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6312144), by using incorporating a [parameter](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9002005), supported by [calculated fields](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685):

### 1) Parameter

Add a [parameter](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9002005) (called `Fruits` here):

- ***Data type***: Text
- ***Permitted values***: List of values

Then enter the following values (with **All** set as the default value, containing the entire unfiltered data set):

- All
- Apple
- Orange
- Pear
- Apple and Orange
- Apple and Pear
- Orange and Pear

[image: fruits_parameter]

### 2) Calculated Fields

Create the [calculated fields](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) below at the [data source](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685#data-source-vs-chart-specific-calculated-fields). Note that the first six calculated fields (beginning with `2.1) HIDE_Apple` and ending with `2.6) HIDE_Orange and Pear`) contain the word **HIDE** to indicate that they can be hidden (otherwise the fields list in the data source will be cluttered) as they are used as support fields in the [`CASE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724) statement (`2.7) Fruits_CASE`).

#### `2.1) HIDE_Apple`

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Fruit Selection, "Apple")
```

#### `2.2) HIDE_Orange`

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Fruit Selection, "Orange")
```

#### `2.3) HIDE_Pear`

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Fruit Selection, "Pear")
```

#### `2.4) HIDE_Apple and Orange`

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Fruit Selection, "(Apple|Orange)")
```

#### `2.5) HIDE_Apple and Pear`

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Fruit Selection, "(Apple|Pear)")
```

#### `2.6) HIDE_Orange and Pear`

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Fruit Selection, "(Orange|Pear)")
```

#### `2.7) Fruits_CASE`

```
CASE Fruits
  WHEN "All" THEN Fruit Selection
  WHEN "Apple" THEN 2.1) HIDE_Apple
  WHEN "Orange" THEN 2.2) HIDE_Orange
  WHEN "Pear" THEN 2.3) HIDE_Pear
  WHEN "Apple and Orange" THEN 2.4) HIDE_Apple and Orange
  WHEN "Apple and Pear" THEN 2.5) HIDE_Apple and Pear
  WHEN "Orange and Pear" THEN 2.6) HIDE_Orange and Pear
  ELSE NULL
END
```

Once that's done, the data source would look like:

[image: fields_data_source]

### 3) Controls, Charts & Filters

#### 3.1) Control

- **[Control](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6312144)**:  [Fixed-size list](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/11335992)
- ***Control field***: `Fruits`

[image: control_fruits]

#### 3.2) Pivot Table

Create a [pivot table](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7516660):

- ***Date range dimension***: `date`
- ***Row dimension***: `Person`
- ***Column dimension***: `2.7) Fruits_CASE`
- ***Metric***: `Record Count`

[image: pivot_table_fruits]

#### 3.3) Filter

`NULL` values created in the `2.7) Fruits_CASE` field can be hidden by using the [filter](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6291066):

```
Exclude 2.7) Fruits_CASE Is NULL
```

[image: filter_null]

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/b1432435-1cb3-4ca1-977b-78bc9fc5992e) (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/103S4fQaqAP79ctl8Ng1iNw-iPh2cW2sDLstxzaNz8aE/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image: gif]